# Multiple icons stored in one image file

Tags: image, icons, sprite-sheet

Is it possible to store multiple small images or icons as parts of a single image, so that my webpage can get all the icons it needs from a single GET request.  This would help my page load faster.

This is an example of the sort of composite image I'm referring to:

http://oi40.tinypic.com/2saaxac.jpg

It seems to me that it is some kind of array of images put into one file. I'm hoping there is some way that i can use each individual icon in the image in a project.

Comment: "the internet simply does not have any information on what i am looking for" That's so funny!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are called **sprite sheets**, there's a great article about them on css-tricks that should help you understand how they work on the web.

[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: Hurray! An SO Q&A without repeats of the same (excellent) answer!